# acts-as-taggable-on ".tagged_with(:match_all => true)" but finding models with more tags?

Tags: ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am looking for a `acts-as-taggable-on` finder that results in selecting all the occurrences that have all the passed tags but allows the occurrences to have more tags.

In [the documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects) looks like it is either *matching exactly all* or *matching any*.

For example:

```
model_1.tag_list = "tag1, tag2, tag3"
model_2.tag_list = "tag1, tag2"
model_3.tag_list = "tag1, tag3"

Models.tagged_with(["tag1", "tag3"], :match_all_flexible => true) # => [model_1, model_3]
```